# HTTPS request in Python

Tags: python, https

I would like to connect to a site via HTTPS in Python 3.2.

I tried

```
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(urlStr, 8443)
    conn.putrequest('GET', '/')
    response = conn.getresponse()  
    print(response.read())
```

but I get

```
    http.client.ResponseNotReady: Request-started
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First of all, if you just want to download something and don't want any special HTTP requests, you should use [`urllib.request`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/urllib.request.html) instead of `http.client`.

```
import urllib.request
r = urllib.request.urlopen('https://paypal.com/')
print(r.read())
```

If you really want to use http.client, you must call [`endheaders`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection.endheaders) after you send the request headers:

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('paypal.com', 443)
conn.putrequest('GET', '/')
conn.endheaders() # <---
r = conn.getresponse()
print(r.read())
```

As a shortcut to `putrequest`/`endheaders`, you can also use the [`request`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection.request) method, like this:

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('paypal.com', 443)
conn.request('GET', '/') # <---
r = conn.getresponse()
print(r.read())
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of `putrequest`, you can use `request`

```
conn.request('GET', '/')
resp = conn.getresponse()
print(resp.read())
```