# communication between web host server and home server

Tags: web-services, networking, encryption, network-programming, communication

I have a web application hosted on an external server. I would create a communication beetwen my home server and the web application. 
I thought something like that:

- my home server send its ip to the web application
- the web application send data to the home server
- my home server send back some data
- I want to implemente a P2P communication between the WebApp and the home server
- it would be bettere if the communication is encrypted
- i dont want to use dynamic dns

Is there something to implement that?

Comment: *"Is there something to implement that?"* - Yes, there are many ways. Yes/No-questions are not particularly useful for Stack Overflow and there are too many possible answers for this question to be answerable.

Comment: *"i dont want to use dynamic dns"* - You don't have to, but you will likely have to deal with NAT-hole punching or opening a port on your home firewall (router).

Answer (score 0):

- There are several types of IP. It can be "grey" and "white".
  "Grey" means that your computer can't be accesses through it.
  "White" IP's can be accessed directly.  Also there are dynamic IP's
  that changes through the time. It all depends from the provider. 
  It's possible that you have "white dynamic" IP but it's pretty rare
  for providers to do.
- It's easier to connect to server because it
  always have "white" permament IP.
- TCP/IP already does most of the work. You just create tcp connection and it stays. You just think about sending data.

---

My suggestion for you is to create something like this:

1. Home server connects to WebApp
2. Home server requests some data and WebApp sends back data
3. Home server sends request containing data and server respondes that all is ok

So you have client-server model. And client always does only requests and server does only responses. And they **do not switch**. It's easier to maintain.

There is common technology of doing that and it includes encryption too.
You should use HTTPS protocol. Https will do all the encryption(and safely exchange keys too) you just worry about certificates(there are ways not to buy certificate but sign them by yourself. It's whole another topic)

So you will send https requests from your home server PC(client) and get responses from server(webApp).

---

As you write on Python you would find this answer helpful for you:
[HTTPS request in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839179/https-request-in-python)

Comment: thank you for your inputs. My target was to implement something like a P2P communication between webapp and the home server (a simple response for my project is not enough). I have found this package in python to implemente that: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyp2p , But it is an experimental version...

Comment: You should edit your question to make your task clear. Response can include files though. Http is very flexible.
So what is your point? What do you want to achieve?
You can create encrypted streams. Problem with pyp2p will be that it will be much harder to implement encryption without preshared keys