# How to use AWS certificate with python requests library?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, python-requests

I have an elastic load balancer running on aws cloud. I have attached a HTTPS listener to it on port 443, and it is using a certificate in certificate manager. I want to send https requests from a python script to the elastic load. I can't figure out the exact api call that I should make to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make https get request to the DNS of the ELB.

To generate HTTPS request use following script quoted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9839316/1844843).

> ```
> import urllib.request
> r = urllib.request.urlopen('<DNS OF ELB>')
> print(r.read())
> ```
>
> If you really want to use http.client, you must call `endheaders`
>   after you send the request headers:
>
> ```
> import http.client
> conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('DNS OF ELB', 443)
> conn.putrequest('GET', '/')
> conn.endheaders() # <---
> r = conn.getresponse()
> print(r.read())
> ```
>
> As a shortcut to `putrequest`/`endheaders`, you can also use the `request`
>   method, like this:
>
> ```
> import http.client
> conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('DOMAIN', 443)
> conn.request('GET', '/') # <---
> r = conn.getresponse()
> print(r.read())
> ```

**Update 1**

For Python 2.7 You can use httplib or urllib2

If you are using `httplib`, HTTPS supports only if the `socket` module was compiled with SSL support.

For urllib2 refer this [article](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/456195/).

Comment: urllib.request doesn't seem to available for python2.7, I have urllib installed, but can't import urllib.requests, traceback says module doesn't exist.